# Clock Trigger Builder Not calling function when scheduled - Google sheets app Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-prediction

I am using the app script provided by Google to access their prediction API through sheets. I am trying to predict thousands of rows at once, however, after 6 minutes the maximum execution time is reached at the code stops.

I implemented a solution that I found using clock trigger builder. Once I run the function it goes for 5 mins, then it stops sets a trigger to recall the function within 2 mins.

The major problem is that the function is not called when scheduled. I see it in the current triggers list, but it never gets called again. Can you please explain why this is occurring.

My intention is to predict as many lines as possible in 5 min then stop set a trigger to call the predict function again within a few minutes start where it left off and continue until ever element has been predicted.

I also need to know how would I store then values in cache so that it would know all the information that it needs when the function is called again.

```
//This is the function that is used to predict a selection of data
function predict() {
  try {
    clearOutput();
    var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var selection = sheet.getActiveSelection();
    var instances = selection.getValues();
    var project_number = getProjectNumber();
    var model_name = getModelName();
    var startRow = stRow; 
    var MAX_RUNNING_TIME = 300000;
    var REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT = 60000;
    for (var i = startRow; i < instances.length; ++i) {
      var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
      if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
        var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger('predict').timeBased().after(REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT);
    builder.create();
    break;
  } else {  
    var result = predictSingleRow(project_number, model_name, instances[i]);
    selection.getCell(i + 1, 1).setValue(result);
  }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Browser.msgBox('ERROR:' + e, Browser.Buttons.OK);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things as to why your code is not functioning as intended:

1) Since you mentioned,"I see it in the current triggers list, but it never gets called again" and looking at your code, I am unsure whether you intended to call the function again after it's execution has completed. If you do, this is because your `for` loop runs for a while until the length of the `instances` is obtained. Nothing in the script suggests that the function needs to be run again once it has finished iterating through `instances`. Refer to this link to see how to [Manage Trigger Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).

2) `var builder = ScriptApp.newTrigger('predict').timeBased().after(REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT);`

This line of your code falls under an `if` condition which stops the execution for 1 minute (value is 60000). Hence, adding 1 minute to the time since execution started. Nowhere are you resetting the `startTime` counter to the time after the waiting time since once the value of `currTime - startTime` has exceeded `MAX_RUNNING_TIME`, the function will keep calling the `if` loop for all iterations of the `for` loop after that. Simply put, if `startTime` was 9:35 and `currTime` was 9:40, after waiting for 1 minute the `currTime` is 9:41 which is still more than the `MAX_RUNNING_TIME`(5 minutes) because value of `startTime` still remains 9:35. Resetting it to 9:41 at this point should resolve your problem.

3) Loosing the `break` in the `if` loop would probably help fix that as well.

**EDIT:**

Add a function as shown in the link I mentioned above:

```
function callTrigger(){
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('predict')
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(30)
      .create();
}
```

Run the function callTrigger once from your editor and you should be good to go. Remember, for minutes you can only pass values 1,5,15 or 30.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, however, I am still getting the same result. What I want to happen is the prediction to run through the list until the time is reached then stop executing wait for a while then start executing again but pick up from where it left off. Removing the

Comment: break did not work. I see the functions in the list for tiggers so the time it says it will be triggered is later then the current time. I wait for the time listed and nothing happens. The function should be called again and the process should resume.

Comment: One of the things is that you are using `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`. Often times, if the sheet is not open it will not work since it's not an Active sheet. Try passing openById instead and see if that works. Also, can you please update your code with the changes you made?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the same problem. The function is simply not being called

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(projectID);
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1]; // "access data on different tabs"
    ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

Comment: The function works fine when I call it myself, but it is not being called when schedule and remains on the current project's triggers list.

Comment: The same thing occured when I used your code to call the trigger ever 5 minutes. The function just doesn't get call even one time. I even tried a simple test in another spread sheet just to print to console a string and had your function call that function and it too just sits in the trigger list but never gets called again. Is there a setting or something that need to be activated in order to use this feature cause no matter what I try I can not get the trigger to work and call a function.

Comment: Since your function is taking longer than 5 minutes to run, I would suggest you set the trigger to 15 minutes or more. So that it is called only after the execution of the function has finished the first time. Another thing to check is the version of the spreadsheet. Do you know if the spreadsheet you're working is an old version of the Google Spreadsheet or the new one?